# Overlap between eigenstates of angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory, quantum-states

Consider the states $\left|j,m_x\right>_x$ and $\left|j,m_z\right>_z$  with total angular momentum $j$ and the angular momentum operators $\hat{S}_x$ and $\hat{S}_y$. In particular, assume that the states satisfy $\hat{S}_x\left|j,m_x\right>_x=m_x\left|j,m_x\right>_x$ and $\hat{S}_z\left|j,m_z\right>_z=m_z\left|j,m_z\right>_z$. I am wondering about the closed form of the overlap between the eigenstates shown, that is, what is the analytical expression for $_x\left<j,m_x\lvert j,m_z \right>_z$.

Comment: $S$, $L$, $J$ are usually spin, orbit, total angular momentum, with quantum numbers $|s, s_z\rangle$, $|l, m\rangle$, $|j, j_z\rangle$ or $3$ in place of $z$.

Answer (score 7):

The transformation that takes you from $S_z$ to $S_x$ is a rotation about $\hat y$ by $\pi/2$ so all eigenstates of $S_x$ are of the form
$$
\vert jm\rangle_x=R^{-1}_y(\pi/2)\vert jm\rangle_z
$$
so that
$$
S_xR^{-1}_y(\pi/2)\vert jm\rangle_z= [R^{-1}_y(\pi/2) S_z R_y(\pi/2)]R^{-1}_y(\pi/2)\vert jm\rangle_z=m R^{-1}_y(\pi/2)\vert jm\rangle_z
$$
Thus, the closed form is
$$
_x\langle jm’\vert jm\rangle_z
=_z\langle jm’\vert R_y(\pi/2)\vert jm\rangle_z=d^{j}_{m’m}(\pi/2)
$$
where $d$ is a
[Wigner little-d function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Wigner_(small)_d-matrix).

(I hope I didn’t mess up the sign between $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$ but aside from this the answer is correct.)

Comment: I think you are right in your signs; checks for j=1/2, unless I messed up myself...